# Cakephp prefix routing not working on Linux - but works on Windows

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3 app and it has different plugins.  The plugins appear to load and accessing them on a dev Windows machine, WAMP, it all works fine.

Once on the CentOS server, the plugin's prefix routing eg 'admin' stops working, getting a missing controller error:
[image]

Log error:

```
2018-04-11 12:40:23 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Contacts could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Contacts',
  'plugin' => 'Contacts',
  'prefix' => 'admin',
  '_ext' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /myapp/contacts/admin/contacts
Referer URL: https://***/myapp/anotherplugin/participants
Stack Trace:
#0 /srv/www/myapp/myapp-app/webroot/index.php(36): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#1 /srv/www/myapp/myapp-app/index.php(16): require('/srv/www/mya...')
#2 {main}
```

The controller does exists and contains:

```
namespace Contacts\Controller\Admin;

use Contacts\Controller\AppController;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Authentication\Utility\TimeUtility;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class ContactsController extends AppController{
```

Non-prefix routing seems fime.  The plugins are added in bootstrap.php like this:

```
Plugin::load('Contacts', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);
```

In plugins routing file:

```
<?php
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::plugin('Contacts', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Router::plugin('Contacts', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
    });
});
```

In Apache the app is setup as an alias with mod rewrite - both on WAMP and on the CentOS server:

```
http://server-or-localhost/myapp/
```

Differences between local and server:

- Server is Linux, uppercase/lower case issues?
- Same PHP versions, but
  maybe some modules missing on server PHP?
- The server redirects http to https

Comment: In most cases it's a case-sensitivity issue, so you'll have to show the involved controller file contents and names. Also whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), and a screenshot of the error page as it may contain further details.

Comment: Looking at the error page, does your controller namespace/class/filename look like the example that is being shown there?

Comment: Yes, it does - added it above.

Comment: And does the path/filename match? And are you sure that you've deployed the file? If both is true, then check whether the permissions allow the server/PHP to read the file. Also try redumping the autoloader on the new server.

Comment: Path/filename matches I believe - I pasted the path from the error message and the file was there.  So I think that confirms the file is deployed.  Permission is fine. It's CakePHP 3.2 and PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

Blast!  Check your CakePHP version 3.2.0 has this bug. Fixed in 3.2.1.

https://bakery.cakephp.org/2016/01/30/cakephp_3110_and_321_released.html

It's working now.